# The meaning of "knocked out cold"

Tags: meaning

Would anybody explain the meaning of "knocked out cold" to me, please?

Comment: It is hyperbole expressing an unconscious state. If anyone were actually *knocked-out* and *cold* they would probably be dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of the confusion relates to the use of the term "knockout" and "knocked out" in boxing.  In boxing, a boxer can be "knocked out" while still conscious and moving, if the boxer partially arises, but fails to fully rise to his (or her) feet before a count of ten, they are considered "knocked out", but are most certainly not "out cold".  The phrase "out cold" typically means fully unconscious, not responding, as with someone in a deep sleep.  Boxing further has the concept of a "technical knockout" which does not involve unconsciousness, but rather a boxer who is unable to continue for medical safety, reasons such as being unable to defend themselves against further attacks, e.g., blood from a cut dripping into their eye(s) and rendering them unable to see.

So "knocked out cold" is a conglomeration of these concepts. The "out cold" part is a description of their current condition, and the "knocked" (out) part is describing that it resulted from a physical blow or impact.

Thus "knocked out cold" would be appropriately descriptive for someone who was "knocked" fully unconscious by a physical impact, usually a blow to the head, and is totally unresponsive for a period of time.  It does not describe the length of time the unresponsiveness lasts, though it would be generally understood to last at least a few seconds.

Comment: @Sergey - Keep in mind that the phrase would be used to describe the incident or process which "knocked him out cold". A person who is unconscious would be described as "out cold", rather than "knocked out cold", since the "out cold" part clearly requires that he be "knocked out" in the first place. "What happened to him?" "I don't know. He's out cold."

Comment: I agree overall with comments by @WhatRoughBeast.  The state of being "out cold" can result from many different ways of being "knocked out".  One can also be "knocked out" by a sedative drug, for example. "Knocked out" has usages that don't always imply being unconscious, so adding "cold" can clarify this aspect.